# How to show the last three scores of the user of the quiz they took

Tags: python

I made a quiz with three different users on it in Python. I need to save and show the last three scores the user who is logged in got for taking the quiz and I don't know how to do that.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import sys   

c2 = 0
Score = 0
CU1 = "Scott"
CU2 = "alexander"
CU3 = "Lisa1"
CP1 = "heyall"
CP2 = "password"
CP3 = "Simpson"
Questions = ["True or False? CPU stands for Central Processing Unit?", "True or False? On average magnetic tape is more expensive than an Optical disk.", "True or False? A Binary Search looks for items in an ordered list.", "True or False? Extended ASCII covers all major languages.",  "True or False? Procedures always must take parameters.", "True or False? In flow charts input/output is represented in a diamond.", "True or False? The world's largest WAN is the cloud.", "True or False? POP3 is used to retrieve emails from a server.", "True or False? In hexidecimal the binary number 01001110 equals 4E.", "True or False? An interpreter is only required once to run the program."]
Answers = ["True", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False"]
uninput = input("Please type in your username to continue:")

if uninput == CU1 or CU2 or CU3:
    Auth = True
else:
    Auth = False

if Auth == False:
    print("Username not found")
    sys.exit("Username incorrect!")
    
    
if Auth == True:
    print("Username found!")
    psinput = input("Please type in your password to continue:")
    
if psinput == CP1 or CP2 or CP3:
    Auth2 = True
else:
    Auth2 = False

if Auth2 == False:
    print("Password incorrect!")
    sys.exit("Password incorrect")

if Auth2 == True:
    import random

if Auth == True and Auth2 == True:
    Count = 1

if CU1 == uninput and CP1 == psinput:
    Count = Count + 1
elif CU2 == uninput and CP2 == psinput:
    Count = Count + 1
elif CU3 == uninput and CP3 == psinput:
    Count = Count + 1
else:
    Count = 0
    sys.exit("No access granted!")

if Count == 2:
    print("Commencing Quiz")
    while len(Questions) > 0:
        Question = random.randint(0, (len(Questions))-1)
        Ans = input(Questions[Question])
        if Ans == Answers[Question]:
            print("Correct!")
            Questions.remove(Questions[Question])
            Answers.remove(Answers[Question])
            Score = Score + 1
            c2 = c2 + 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            Questions.remove(Questions[Question])
            Score = Score
            c2 = c2 + 1
        
if Score == 10:
    print("Well done sport! You got", Score ,"I'm so proud of you!")
elif Score == 9:
    print("Well done sport! You got", Score ,"I'm so proud of you!")
if Score == 8:
    print("Well done sport! You got", Score ,"I'm so proud of you!")
elif Score == 7:
    print("Good job you got", Score ,"! It's not so bad! I'm proud!")
elif Score == 6:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 5:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 4:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 3:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 2:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 1:
    print("Try again. You only got", Score,"/10")
elif Score == 0:
    print("You're a disgrace! You only got", Score,"/10!!!")
```

uninput is short for username input, and psinput is short for password input, if anyone's wondering.

Comment: do you want to show it between multiple openings of the program?

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're asking here. specifically, what's your question?

Comment: `if uninput == CU1 or CU2 or CU3:` <-- this doesn't do what you think it does (it's always True no matter what you set `uinput` to be)

Comment: I'm asking for a way to store and print the previous 3 Scores that the user who is "logged in" obtained

Comment: you're going to need to be more specific. there are many ways to store data. are you writing to a database? to disk? keep it in memory?

Comment: append scores to list ie. `all_scores` and later use `all_scores[-3:]` to get 3 last scores

Comment: not `if uninput == CU1 or CU2 or CU3:` but `if uninput == CU1 or uninput == CU2 or uninput == CU3:` or `if uninput in (CU1, CU2, CU3):` and then you could keep users on list and use `if uninput in list_of_users:`

Comment: BTW: instead of `if Score == 10:` `elif Score == 9:` `if Score == 8:` with the same code you can write shorter `if Score in (10, 9, 8):` or `if  10 >= Score >= 8:` and the same `if 6 >= Score >= 1:`

Comment: BTW: if you need separated scores for every user then create dictionary with lists `all_scores = {"Scott": [], ...}` and then apped to `all_scores[username]` and get `all_scores[username][-3:]` And you can save and load it using module `json` or `pickle`

Comment: BTW: it would be more readable if you use names `username`, `password` instead of `uninput` and `psinput`

Comment: BTW: all import put at the beginning - `import random`. Using `if Auth2 == True: import random` doesn't make your script faster but it makes it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code, but since that's not the question I won't go into that here.

For the next time, try to make your question more concise. What are you trying to accomplish specifically? As far as I can make out, you're just trying to store some text, per user.

### How to store something with Python?

As a first step, try to formulate what exactly you want to store. What should the *variable* look like?
For this case, it might be something like `lastScores = [6, 8, 9]`.

Now, we want to store and load that. How do you want to actually store it?

- In a database?
- Just keep it in memory for when you re-execute the program?
- Save all scores together into one `myquiz`-file?
- Store scores for each user in a seperate file?

Just to give you some code, I'll assume you want to store it as one file per user, as plain text, always to the same folder.

## Saving:

```
scorefile = open('C:/Path/to/quiz/folder/' + uninput + '_scores.txt', mode = 'w')
scorefile.write(', '.join([str(score) for score in lastScores]))
scorefile.close()
```

Here, we open a file `C:/Path/to/quiz.folder/Scott_scores.txt`, for `w`riting.

As it's a textfile, we transform the scores to a line of text. Every element of lastScores is transformed into a `str`, and all values are joined with a comma and space. So what we write is `6, 8, 9`

Finally, we close the file so other processes can open it later.

## Loading

Not that different:

```
scorefile = open('C:/Path/to/quiz/folder/' + uninput + '_scores.txt', mode = 'r')
lastScores = [int(score) for score in scorefile.read().split(', ')]
scorefile.close()
```

We open the file, this time for `r`eading.

The last scores are gotten by reading the file, splitting on comma+space. And each of the elements is transformed to an `int`

And we close the file again.

If you're not sure the file already exists, you can change it into this:

```
try:
    scorefile = open('C:/Path/to/quiz/folder/' + uninput + '_scores.txt', mode = 'r')
    lastScores = [int(score) for score in scorefile.read().split(', ')]
    scorefile.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    lastScores = []
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code little bit. The approach used in having input_file.txt which has names and scores and new scores will be appended to this file.

**Input file : input_file.txt**

```
Scott|0
Scott|4
Scott|6
alexander|6
alexander|1
alexander|6
```

alexander|6

**Code**

```
import sys

Score = 0
userDatabase = {"Scott" : "heyall", "alexander" : "password", "Lisa1" : "Simpson"}
Questions = ["True or False? CPU stands for Central Processing Unit?", "True or False? On average magnetic tape is more expensive than an Optical disk.",
             "True or False? A Binary Search looks for items in an ordered list.", "True or False? Extended ASCII covers all major languages.",
             "True or False? Procedures always must take parameters.", "True or False? In flow charts input/output is represented in a diamond.",
             "True or False? The world's largest WAN is the cloud.", "True or False? POP3 is used to retrieve emails from a server.",
             "True or False? In hexidecimal the binary number 01001110 equals 4E.", "True or False? An interpreter is only required once to run the program."]
Answers = ["True", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "True", "False"]
uninput = input("Please type in your username to continue:")

# file_object = open('input_file.txt', 'a')
previos_scores = 0
if uninput in userDatabase.keys():
    print("Username found!")
    psinput = input("Please type in your password to continue:")
    if psinput == userDatabase[uninput]:
        print("Successfully logged in.!! \n Answer following questions.")
        for index,element in enumerate(Questions):
            currentAnswer = input(element)
            if currentAnswer.strip() not in ("True", "False"):
                raise Exception("Answer should be either True or False")
            if currentAnswer.__contains__(Answers[index]) :
                Score += 1
        with open("input_file.txt", "a") as file_object:
            file_object.write(uninput + "|"+ str(Score)+"\n")

        with open("input_file.txt", "r") as file_object_prevscores:
            previos_scores = file_object_prevscores.read()
        print("\nPrevious three scores : ", [x.split("|")[1] for x in previos_scores.split("\n")[-4:-2] if x.__contains__(uninput)],
              "\nThe current score received : ", Score)
    else:
        print("Password incorrect!")
        sys.exit("Password incorrect")
else:
    print("Username not found")
    sys.exit("Username incorrect!")
```

**Output**

```
Please type in your username to continue:alexander
Username found!
Please type in your password to continue:password
Successfully logged in.!! 
 Answer following questions.
True or False? CPU stands for Central Processing Unit?False
True or False? On average magnetic tape is more expensive than an Optical disk.False
True or False? A Binary Search looks for items in an ordered list.False
True or False? Extended ASCII covers all major languages.False
True or False? Procedures always must take parameters.False
True or False? In flow charts input/output is represented in a diamond.False
True or False? The world's largest WAN is the cloud.False
True or False? POP3 is used to retrieve emails from a server.False
True or False? In hexidecimal the binary number 01001110 equals 4E.False
True or False? An interpreter is only required once to run the program.False

Previous scores :  ['1', '6'] 
The current score received :  6
```

Answer (score 0):

To display 3 last scores you have to save scores in file and later read them.

I would keep data in JSON file as dictionary like this

**users.json**

```
{
    "Scott": {
        "password": "heyall",
        "scores": []
    },
    "alexander": {
        "password": "heyall",
        "scores": []
    },
    "Lisa1": {
        "password": "heyall",
        "scores": []
    }
}
```

BTW: Similar way I would keep questions in JSON file

**data.json**

```
[
    {
        "question": "True or False? CPU stands for Central Processing Unit?",
        "answer": "True"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? On average magnetic tape is more expensive than an Optical disk.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? A Binary Search looks for items in an ordered list.",
        "answer": "True"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? Extended ASCII covers all major languages.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? Procedures always must take parameters.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? In flow charts input/output is represented in a diamond.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? The world's largest WAN is the cloud.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? POP3 is used to retrieve emails from a server.",
        "answer": "True"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? In hexidecimal the binary number 01001110 equals 4E.",
        "answer": "False"
    },
    {
        "question": "True or False? An interpreter is only required once to run the program.",
        "answer": "False"
    }
]
```

And then I can read it at start

```
with open('users.json') as fh:
    all_users = json.load(fh)
    
with open('data.json') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)
```

Update after quiz

```
all_users[username]['scores'].append(score)
```

And save it

```
with open('users.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(all_users, fh)
```

And then I may display 3 last scores (or more) using `[-3:]`

```
print('Three last scores:', all_users[username]['scores'][-3:])
```

---

Full code (with other changes)

I uses `random.shuffle(data)` to change order in data and then I can use normal `for`-loop and code is simpler.

```
import sys   
import random
import json

# read data

with open('users.json') as fh:
    all_users = json.load(fh)
    
with open('data.json') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

# login 

username = input("Login: ")
password = input("Password: ")

if username not in all_users.keys():
    print("Username not found")
    sys.exit("Username incorrect!")
    
if password != all_users[username]['password']:
    print("Password incorrect!")
    sys.exit("Password incorrect")

# change questions order

random.shuffle(data)

# ask questions

score = 0

for item in data:
    question = item['question']
    answer   = item['answer']
    
    user_answer = input(question)
    
    if user_answer == answer:
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
    
# keep new score

all_users[username]['scores'].append(score)

# display result    

if 10 >= score >= 8:
    print("Well done sport! You got", score ,"I'm so proud of you!")
elif score == 7:
    print("Good job you got", score ,"! It's not so bad! I'm proud!")
elif 6 >= score >= 1:
    print("Try again. You only got", score,"/10")
elif score == 0:
    print("You're a disgrace! You only got", score,"/10!!!")

print('Three last scores:', all_users[username]['scores'][-3:])

# save it    

with open('users.json', 'w') as fh:
    json.dump(all_users, fh)
```